# How to process input and output streams in Steel Bank Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm trying to figure out how to use the output stream of one program I start with `RUN-PROGRAM` so it can be used as the input of another program started with `RUN-PROGRAM` (i.e., the moral and perhaps literal equivalent of piping). I've tried using a number of combinations of the `:INPUT`, `:OUTPUT` and `:WAIT` keyword arguments, but nothing I've hit 
upon has been productive so far. Any tips would be helpful; for example, how would I go about doing something like `ls | grep lisp` from the shell?

One of my attempts is

```
(defun piping-test () 
  (let ((grep-process (run-program "/usr/bin/grep" '("lisp") 
                                  :input :stream 
                                  :output :stream))) 
    (unwind-protect 
        (with-open-stream (s (process-input grep-process)) 
          (let ((ls-process (run-program "/bin/ls" '() 
                                        :output s))) 
            (when ls-process 
              (unwind-protect 
                  (with-open-stream (o (process-output grep-process)) 
                   (loop 
                      :for line := (read-line o nil nil) 
                      :while line 
                      :collect line)) 
               (process-close ls-process))))) 
     (when grep-process (process-close grep-process)))))
```

Running this in a SLIME REPL causes everything to hang until I break 
with `C-c C-c`, so it's pretty obviously not the right thing, but I'm 
not sure how to change it so it is the right thing.

**EDIT:** Adding `:WAIT NIL` to both `RUN-PROGRAM` invocations, or to only the invocation for `grep`, doesn't do the trick. In that case, the function will hang, and breaking with `C-c C-c` gets a stack trace indicating that there's a local function (defined via `FLET`) called `SB-UNIX:SELECT` that has hung.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got a working answer from Raymond Toy on [comp.lang.lisp](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.lisp/msg/6d86d149d8492084). His solution was for CMUCL, but it worked with the essentially identical `RUN-PROGRAM` function on the closely related SBCL, and with minor changes it will work on CCL as well, because CCL's `RUN-PROGRAM` is basically a clone of the one from CMUCL/SBCL.

The secret, as it were, is to set up the `ls` process first, and then provide its output stream to the `grep` process as input, like so:

```
(defun piping-test2 () 
  (let ((ls-process (run-program "/bin/ls" '() 
                                 :wait nil 
                                 :output :stream))) 
    (unwind-protect 
        (with-open-stream (s (process-output ls-process)) 
          (let ((grep-process (run-program "/usr/bin/grep" '("lisp") 
                                          :input s 
                                          :output :stream))) 
            (when grep-process 
              (unwind-protect 
                  (with-open-stream (o (process-output grep-process)) 
                    (loop 
                       :for line := (read-line o nil nil) 
                       :while line 
                       :collect line)) 
                (process-close grep-process))))) 
      (when ls-process (process-close ls-process)))))
```

I also experimented with omitting the `:WAIT NIL` argument from the `RUN-PROGRAM` call for `ls`, and it worked just as well.

Answer (score 2):

A portable solution across implementations, using UIOP (included in ASDF, shipped with the implementations):

```lisp
(uiop:run-program "grep lisp"
                   :input
                   (uiop:process-info-output
                    (uiop:launch-program "ls"
                                         :output :stream))
                   :output :string)
```

`launch-program` is synchronous and outputs to a stream, while `run-program` is async, and we ask it to output to a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `:wait nil` to your arguments to `run-program`. That should have both your grep and your ls running in the background. As is, you're starting the grep process, waiting for that to finish, then starting the ls you're intending to feed into the grep process. Alas, since you're waiting for the grep to finish, you never get that far.

Answer (score 1):

Relatedly, but perhaps not spot on to your question, you could do:

```
(with-output-to-string (s)
      (ccl:run-program "sh" (list "-c" "ls a/directory/somewhere/*.lisp") :output s)
      s)
```

or

```
(with-output-to-string (s)
      (ccl:run-program "sh" (list "-c" "ls /a/directory/somewhere/*.lisp | wc -l") :output s)
      s)
```

or

```
(with-output-to-string (s)
      (ccl:run-program "ssh" (list "a-user@some-ip" "sh -c ls /a/directory/somewhere/on/remote/server/*.lisp | wc -l") :output s)
      s)
```

And, of course, you can use

```
(format nil "ls ~a" directory)
```

To get input, you can do something like:

```
(with-output-to-string (out)
      (format t "~%Enter your sudo password:~%")
      (with-input-from-string (s (read))
        (ccl:run-program "ssh" (list *remote* "sudo cat /etc/init.d/nginx")  :input s :output out))
      out)
```